# npm run watch is not working on Ubuntu after config with TailwindCSS

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix, tailwind-css

Just started watching a series and installed TailwindCSS after configs in `webpack`, now when I'm trying to run `npm run watch` its throwings errors like `npm ERR! Linux 5.3.0-40-generic`.
I'm on `ubuntu` and Laravel framework.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually, I directly installed Tailwind as following the series. 
The solution was I run `npm install` then `npm run watch` it woked.